# how to resolve an issue with If condition never be true in Django

Tags: django

This is a potion of view function written in Django. This clause never executed even though if the condition is true:

```
def search(request):

    query_cc = request.GET.get('h_qcc') # category variable
    query_sc = request.GET.get('h_qsc') # sub_category variable
    print('###################')
    print(query_sc)



    dd = Post_Category.objects.filter(category_name__iexact=query_cc).get()
    print(';;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;')
    print(dd) # print the category 
    ddd = Post_Sub_Category.objects.filter(category_name__category_name__iexact=dd)
    print('ooooooooooooooooo')
    print(ddd) # print the sub_category variable for the category variable that is passed through the request of 
    if query_sc in  Post_Sub_Category.objects.filter(category_name__category_name__iexact=query_cc): # if the sub_category passed in variable query_sc is existing in a list of choices based on category that is passed in query_cc variable. Unfortunately this clause never executed even though it is true
        all_p_sub_category = Post_Sub_Category.objects.filter(category_name__category_name__iexact=query_cc)
        print('+++++++++++++++++++')
        print (all_p_sub_category)
```

This is sample of the out put that the if statement should be executed:

```
###################
car
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
for sale
ooooooooooooooooo
<QuerySet [<Post_Sub_Category: car>, <Post_Sub_Category: spare parts>, <Post_Sub_Category: truck>,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
Post_Sub_Category.objects.filter(category_name__category_name__iexact=query_cc)
```

will return a `QuerySet` object. `query_sc` is, evidently, a string. If you search for a string in a `QuerySet` you will not find it. However, your filter *already checks* for what you want, which is whether a category name of one of the `Post_Sub_Category` objects matches `query_cc` exactly. So, rewrite your line as:

```
if Post_Sub_Category.objects.filter(category_name__category_name__iexact=query_cc):
```

This works because an empty `QuerySet` will evaluate to `False` ("a falsey value," to be precise).

For future reference, the title of your post is wrong- the if is actually evaluating to `False`. In general, assume your code is wrong, not the programming language itself. You could have tested this with another judiciously placed print statement of the boolean value of the conditional statement itself.